# Reasonable way to copy files to a new SD card using a Mac

Tags: sd-card, file-transfer, macos

I have a Mac and want to transfer about 30 GB of data to a larger SD card for use with a new Android phone.

The phone in question is a Galaxy Stratosphere II.

There doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to do this.

So far I have tried

- Copying using Android File Transfer, with the phone connected via USB.  This seemed to work, running at about 10MB/s, but didn't retain the file timestamps, which is unacceptable to me.  Since the app seems to only provide access via a drag-and-drop interface, I don't think there's a way to use it to copy files while retaining timestamps.
- Copying using `scp -pr` via `SSHDroid` running on the phone, via another wifi network.  This also worked, retaining timestamp information, but was painfully slow (<1 MB/s).
- Plugging the SDCard into my MacBook Pro.  This doesn't work: it is not a recognized filesystem.  I tried using a third-party SD Card reader also, with the same result.
- Using `adb push` to copy files over a USB connection.  This also doesn't work, even when I add `/.` to the end as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16336345/192812).

[`simple-mtpfs`](https://github.com/phatina/simple-mtpfs) might be an option, but the given build instructions reference non-existent executables.

[Alt Mounter](http://nexus.zteo.com/beta/) also sounds like it does what I want, but is indicated as being "***EXTREMELY BETA***" and thus is not something I'd prefer to trust with my important files.

When I upgraded a different SD card, I experimented with copying files to the SD card in a connected reader via a Linux VM.  This seemed to work but would mysteriously cut out after copying a fraction of the data.  I think that time I ended up just using `scp` and leaving it to run for a day or two.

I'm continuing to dig into this, but perhaps someone can save me some time.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Both OSX and Android provide basic POSIX utilities, so I ended up going old school on this one:

```
$ tar czv "$PATH_TO_ORIGINAL_SDCARD" | split -b 2048m - sdcard-
```

This command creates 2GB-sized chunks of an archive of the sdcard contents, with names like `sdcard-aa`, `sdcard-ab`, and so on.  The 2GB split is necessary because Android File Transfer can only copy files of 4GB or less in size.

Then I copied the files over to the phone using (surprise!) Android File Transfer and recombined and unarchived them in Terminal Emulator* using this command:

```
$ cat sdcard-* | tar xzv
```

### *: it was actually a  bit more complicated than this.  Gory details:

So actually Android *doesn't* really come with basic POSIX utilities, or at least if it does, they are not readily available to the Terminal Emulator app.

I thought that it did because [SSHDroid](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=sshdroid&so=1&c=apps) provides these utilities via `busybox`.  I suspect that Android doesn't allow processes to execute files that their user does not own; this would explain why there is no app available that installs `busybox` for non-rooted phones.

`busybox` is a utility that can execute any of a large number of POSIX commands, depending on what name it is called with.  People arrange for it to be called with names other than `busybox` by creating *symbolic links* to it with names like, for example, `tar`.

However, it turns out that it *is* possible to install busybox in your own Terminal Emulator app home directory.  So that's what I did.  Steps:

- Grab the file [`busybox-android`](https://github.com/Gnurou/busybox-android/raw/master/busybox-android) from [the eponymous github project](https://github.com/Gnurou/busybox-android).
- Get it onto your device (see above!).  Put it somewhere public that you'll have access to from a Terminal Emulator session.  Just call it `busybox`.
- Start a Terminal Emulator session.  Make a directory `~/bin` and copy the `busybox` file from the public place you put it to that new directory.

  - Since the `cp` command is not available in a Terminal Emulator session (!) do it this way: `cat $PATH_TO_BUSYBOX/busybox > ~/bin/busybox`
- Now `cd ~/bin` and create a symbolic link: `ln -s busybox tar`.
- Now you should be able to `cd /storage/extSdCard/` and concatenate and extract the contents of your archive files to it using `cat $PATH_TO_ARCHIVE/sdcard-* | ~/bin/tar xzv`.
- It will be extracted with whatever prefix directories were the path to the sdcard contents when you created the archive set, e.g. `/Volumes/oldphone/`.  So now move everything from that subdirectory (we'll call it `$OLD_SDCARD_CONTENTS`) to the root of your current SD card.

  - `sh` (the shell used by Terminal Emulator) doesn't seem to have any way to select all the hidden files in a directory, so I ran `bash` to do this.  Under bash, `mv $PATH_TO_FILES/.[^.]* $DEST` will move all hidden files.  Remember that you have to access `bash` via a symlink to `busybox`, or just do this part via `ssh` (which is actually what I did).

Whew!  Glad that's over.  I really hope I don't end up accepting this answer; there should be a much easier way to do all of this.

Of course, I could have just untarred the archive in an `ssh` session from my computer, but this would have required me to run my computer for however long it was going to take.  Plus, like, **of course** busybox should be available in Terminal Emulator.